# Facebook app posts are not shown to users

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having a problem with a small app I've created to post images/videos to my enterprise page, all posts that the app is publishing can only be seen by me, nobody else is able to see them. They go to my enterprise page's posted items an all the posts published by the app do not appear, they can only see the posts that I've manually published, but if I use my facebook account to go to my enterprise page I can properly see all app posts (and all the manually published posts also). Does anybody know what I'm missing?

PD: I've still the app in "development mode", and my app is using a "never expiring" token to post to my enterprise page.

Comment: "I've still the app in "development mode"" - that may be the problem

Comment: Content published by an app in dev mode can only be seen by people with a role in the app.